# Different Data sets for classification and timeseries analysis?

Tags: algorithm, dataset, time-series, classification, data-mining

i'm new to Predictive Analytics and want to analyze some data with timeseries and classification algorithms. I have to prepare the data sets myself, so I wanted to ask if I have to create different datasets for each analysis?
If so, are there any rules I can follow?

thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: NO, you can build a time series data and use it also for classification

Long answer!: Time series is a model of data representation that always integrate with time or time periods. You can build a time series data and label it, So you can classify the model to different class and use classification algorithm to predict classes.
It's good to read the classification articles to improve your sight.

Notice the different between classification and regression. classification is used for discreet values and regression used for continuous values: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141381/regression-vs-classification

Also time series might become advance concept in some situation. it's not such an easy task in some problem. there is some statistical concepts(e.g ARMA and...) that you must use in order to good and efficient data mining task.

If you familiar with R, this is a good: http://www.rdatamining.com/examples/time-series-clustering-classification

for python, read this: http://alexminnaar.com/time-series-classification-and-clustering-with-python.html